# Can I load a Node and its Term details using one function?

Tags: nodes, taxonomy-terms

I'm trying to load a set of nodes in my module but the dump of the node array only shows the Term's as Id numbers. It appears I then have to use Term_load to get the titles and fields from these terms. so I'm currently doing

```
$node = Node_load_mulitple($nids)
foreach $node
Taxonomy_term_load($node->taxid)
```

thats obviously not semantically correct but hopefully you get the idea, is this really what I need to do, it seems long winded?